# How to access to a specific values in a dataframe based on the index values using loc[i,j]

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I have data in a [txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUSdiDzm_hjn8Iwze64-uUflyVZCv84m/view?usp=sharing), I converted it in a dataframe (data3), I renamed the index to running from -6 to +5, and now, in a for loop, I want to access to specific values of the dataframe  using iloc command, but I dont get the correct values.

[The dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90XKH.png)

if I use data3.iloc[-6,1] I was expecting a return value = -6 but instead, I get -20

data3.iloc[-5,1] I was expecting =-20 but instead I got -6

data3.iloc[-4,1] I was expecting = -28 but instead I got  -7

Can anybody helped me please? It is important for me to preserve the index from -6 to +5
Here is my code. Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data= pd.read_csv('perfilprueba.txt',delimiter=' ')

## This is because when I read the txt doesnt read dist and amp as diferent 
columns
data_drop = data.drop(data.columns[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6,7]], axis=1) 
data2=data_drop.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 5": "amp"})

## These are two index I will use later
m=int(round(len(data2.index)))
n=int(round(m/2))

## This is because I wanted that my data had index values from -6 to 5+ AND
## also a column with values from -6 to +5

r = pd.Series(np.linspace(-n, n-1,m))  
data2['r'] = r 
erre = pd.Series(np.linspace(-n, n-1,m))  
data2['erre']=erre 
data3=data2.set_index('r')

## Now I want to run a for loop
## that returns me the values of the "amp" column as r moves from -6 to +5

ap=[]
for r in range(-n,n):
     a = data3.loc[[r],['amp']]
     ap   += [a]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.iloc` is a "purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position" (from [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)), meaning that when you are calling `data3.iloc[-5, 1]`, you are actually fetching from the second column of the 5th line from the end of your dataframe.

In your case, I would use `pandas.DataFrame.at` (doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)), though in this case, you can also use `pandas.DataFrame.loc`.

The script would look like:

```
# reading the data (the "sep=\s+" parameter does what is needed)
data3 = pd.read_csv('perfilprueba.txt', sep="\s+")

m = int(round(len(data3.index)))
n = int(round(m/2))

# changing the index so it starts at -n
data3.index -= n
data3['erre'] = data3.index

ap = []
for r in range(-n,n):
    # note that you have to use the column name here
    a = data3.at[r,"amp"]
    ap.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Access a single value for a row/column pair by integer position.
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)
ap=[]
for r in range(-n,n):
a = data3.**loc**[r].**iat**[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)
ap   += [a]